# Extracting HTML element with Java and XPath

Tags: java, html, xml, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to extract the latitude and longitude of an address. Here is the coding.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   int responseCode = 0;
   String api = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=9%20Edinburgh%20Place,%20Centrall&sensor=false&components=country:HK&language=en";         

   URL url = new URL(api);

   HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
   httpConnection.connect();
   responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
   if(responseCode == 200) {
       DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();;
       Document document = builder.parse(httpConnection.getInputStream());
       XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
       XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();      
       XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/GeocodeResponse/status");
       String status = (String)expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING);
      if(status.equals("OK")) {     
          expr = xpath.compile("//*[@id=\"collapsible6\"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span[2]");
          Object results = expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
          NodeList nodes = (NodeList) results; 
          System.out.println(nodes.getLength());

          for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++){
             System.out.println("latitude: " + nodes.item(i).getNodeValue()); 
          }

          expr = xpath.compile("//geometry/location/lng");
          String lng = (String)expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING);
          System.out.println("longitude: " + lng);
      } else      
          throw new Exception("Error from the API - response status: "+status);       
  }
}}
```

I have copied the xpath by inspecting the web element and tried to implement it for latitude but it keeps giving me 0 for nodes.getLength(); however, it works well for longitude. 
If I want to keep the HTML element and make use of it with XPath, how should the code change?

Comment: I would suggest [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) if you are dealing with HTML. xpath's aren't really a great idea for parsing HTML.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an error in your code on this line:

```
expr = xpath.compile("//*[@id=\"collapsible6\"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span[2]");
```

Shouldn't it be this?

```
expr = xpath.compile("//geometry/location/lat");
```

Comment: Yea, expr = xpath.compile("//geometry/location/lat"); can do that
But I am looking any ways that I can use 
//*[@id=\"collapsible6\"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span[2]  when I copy this when I inspect HTML Element but not the HTML source code